# Why can't I have a for loop inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I'm trying to extract data from an array inside an array of objects, then push the data into a new array using nested for of loops. With just one for of loop it works, but with nested for of loops it gives me the following error:

> TypeError: TypeError: _iterator4[typeof Symbol === "function"
>   ?Symbol.iterator : "@@iterator"] is not a function. (In
>   '_iterator4typeof Symbol === "function" ? Symbol.iterator :
>   "@@iterator"', '_iterator4[typeof Symbol === "function" ?
>   Symbol.iterator :"@@iterator"]' is undefined)

I've already tried using while loops and `for(i=0;i<blah.length;i++).`

This is my code.

```
  let approvals=[]
  for(let task of this.props.currentSubscriptionData.subData.tasks){
    if(task.taskupdates.length!=0){
      for(let approval of task){
        aprrovals.push(approval)
      }
    }
  }
```

The following works just fine.

```
  let approvals=[]
  for(let task of this.props.currentSubscriptionData.subData.tasks){
    if(task.taskupdates.length!=0){
      console.log('hi')
    }
  }
```

Data structure simplified: the Initial Array is

`this.props.currentSubscriptionData.subData.tasks`

```
Array [
  Object {
    "taskupdates": Array [
      Object {
        "approval_amount_required": 100000,
      },
      Object {
        "approval_amount_required": 150000,
      },
      Object {
        "approval_amount_required": 50000,
      },
      Object {
        "approval_amount_required": 50000,         },
    ],
  },
  Object {
    "taskupdates": Array [],

  },
  Object {
    "taskupdates": Array [],
  },
]
```

Comment: How is your data structured?

Comment: Did you mean `for (let approval of task.taskupdates)`? It looks like perhaps you can't iterate over `task`.

Comment: thank you! it's almost working now, I'm getting `can't find variable approvals` when pushing into the empty array. is it out of scope somehow?

Comment: you've spelled it `aprrovals` with two 'r's. And one 'p'.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys:) working now.

Comment: Just as a general point, which has done me well over 10 years of working in the software industry, in general, it's not your programming language that's broken. It's not that you've hit some weird edge-case "can't have a for loop in a for loop" or "is it somehow weirdly out of scope". It's 99% of the time a simple mistake you've made, and you just haven't seen it yet :-)

Comment: I completely agree, but sometimes us programmers just look over our code 100 times and miss the same tiny mistake. That's why I need an extra pair of eyes to look over it for me :D. Thanks again guys

Answer (score 0):

Second loop:
`for(let approval of task.taskupdates)`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.